# Android Studio, app crashes when making a CustomTab with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I want to make a CustomTab to eliminate horizontal scrolling when clicking between tabs in TabLayout. So I created a CustomTab class that extends ViewPager and get error when app is run.

[image]

In XML file I put:

```
<com.example.nickmanes.tabbar.CustomTab
```

Android Monitor tells me the error is:

```
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.nickmanes.tabbar.CustomTab cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TabLayout at com.example.nickmanes.tabbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
```

When I click on MainActivity to this yellow highlighted code:

```
   TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
```

What should I be adding in CustomTab to make it work?

Comment: please add the error log to be able to help you

Comment: Read the error. You are trying to cast a ViewPager to a TabLayout.

Comment: I read the error, I'm aware, how do I connect TabLayout to ViewPager then?

Comment: Have you checked what kind of view is the R.id.tabs? If the tabs is a CustomTab (which is a ViewPager), you are using the wrong view here to create the TabLayout.

You must create on your xml a viewpager and a tablayout views and on your class you'll create each object with the respective kind of views.